# Linq Select Group By

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the following class structure :

```
public class PriceLog
{
   public DateTime LogDateTime {get; set;}
   public int Price {get; set;}
}
```

For a **List< PriceLog >** I want a Linq query to generate an output which is equivalent to the data represented as below:

LogDateTime | AVG(Price)
Jan 2012    | 2000
Feb 2012    | 3000

Simply : I want to compute the average price over each month of the year.
Note: LogDateTime property should be formatted as `LogDateTime.ToString("MMM yyyy")`

I have tried the following, but not sure whether it will generate the desired result:

```
var result = from priceLog in PriceLogList
                         group priceLog by priceLog.LogDateTime.ToString("MMM yyyy") into dateGroup
                         select new PriceLog { GoldPrice = (int)dateGroup.Average(p => p.GoldPrice), SilverPrice = (int)dateGroup.Average(p => p.SilverPrice)};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will give you sequence of anonymous objects, containing date string and two properties with average price:

```
var query = from p in PriceLogList
            group p by p.LogDateTime.ToString("MMM yyyy") into g
            select new { 
               LogDate = g.Key,
               AvgGoldPrice = (int)g.Average(x => x.GoldPrice), 
               AvgSilverPrice = (int)g.Average(x => x.SilverPrice)
            };
```

If you need to get list of PriceLog objects:

```
var query = from p in PriceLogList
            group p by p.LogDateTime.ToString("MMM yyyy") into g
            select new PriceLog { 
               LogDateTime = DateTime.Parse(g.Key),
               GoldPrice = (int)g.Average(x => x.GoldPrice), 
               SilverPrice = (int)g.Average(x => x.SilverPrice)
            };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    from p in PriceLog
    group p by p.LogDateTime.ToString("MMM") into g
    select new 
    { 
        LogDate = g.Key.ToString("MMM yyyy"),
        GoldPrice = (int)dateGroup.Average(p => p.GoldPrice), 
        SilverPrice = (int)dateGroup.Average(p => p.SilverPrice) 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try it like this:

```
var result =
        from priceLog in PriceLogList
        group priceLog by priceLog.LogDateTime.ToString("MMM yyyy") into dateGroup
        select new {
            LogDateTime = dateGroup.Key,
            AvgPrice = dateGroup.Average(priceLog => priceLog.Price)
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = priceLog.GroupBy(s => s.LogDateTime.ToString("MMM yyyy")).Select(grp => new PriceLog() { LogDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(grp.Key), Price = (int)grp.Average(p => p.Price) }).ToList();
```

I have converted it to int because my Price field was int and Average method return double .I hope this will help